# What hash algorithms are supported by modern Javascript?

Tags: javascript, hash

I would like to generate SHA1 or similar hashes using only client-side Javascript. In other words, using the Javascript engines provided with IE, FF, and Webkit. I am wondering what hash implementations exist?

Comment: There exist many. Google is your friend. (Example: http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-sha1.html )

Comment: @user1150525 - I think the OP is looking for an implementation using only the JS engine in the browser. I was just searching for the same thing myself last night to avoid a dependency on a third party library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there are any built directly into the browser, but there are some well-documented implementations.

The best I have found is http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/ which is available via CDN and supports:

- MD5
- SHA-1
- SHA-256
- AES
- DES
- Rabbit
- MARC4
- HMAC
- HMAC-MD5
- HMAC-SHA1
- HMAC-SHA256
- PBKDF2

If security matters then use an algorithm that hasn't been broken (yet) and is less subject to various forms of attack (wikipedia has a nice breakdown at the bottom of [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)).

Based on the lack of answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670909/is-there-any-builtin-javascript-string-hash-function-in-newest-browsers), it doesn't seem like this is native browser functionality. I wish there was, but I could see issues arising from relying on the browser. For example, if a flaw was discovered in an algorithm, it would be difficult to move your users to a new algorithm until you knew all of their browsers supported it (and they had upgraded). If you control the hashing algorithm, then you can deploy a new script whenever you wish.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about built-in hash implementations other than what's already used for associative arrays, but here are some sample implementations with code.

SHA

- http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha1.html
- http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-sha1.html
- http://jssha.sourceforge.net/

MD5 (with some others included)

- http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/

Comment: I also found [Mootool's version](https://github.com/sixtyseconds/mootools-string-cryptography/blob/master/Source/String.SHA-1.js) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/712736).

Answer (score 0):

Movable Type has published a js implementation of SHA1 here:
   http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha1.html

I'm sure there are plenty of other implementations.